# Insert specific columns from schema table to another schema table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am unable to find a specific answer to this question and what I have tried does not seem to work. How do I copy specific columns from one table in 1 schema to another schema table? Is that possible?

This is what I tried and it does not seem to work. Both the schemas are in the same database.

```
INSERT INTO public.t_movie (movie_id,movie_name)
SELECT
    MOVIE_ID,movie_name
FROM
    test.t_movies;
```

This is the error that I am getting,

```
ERROR: ERROR: column "movie_id" does not exist
Hint: There is a column named "movie_id" in table "t_movie", 
but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. 
Position: 58
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for `test.t_movies` - apparently it does not have a column named `movie_id` ([edit] your question do not post code in comments)

Comment: share table structure that helps to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that `movie_id` is generated automatically on inserts (say, if it is declared as `serial`).  If this is the case, then don't insert it:

```
INSERT INTO public.t_movie (movie_name)
    SELECT m.movie_name
    FROM test.t_movies m;
```

Comment: It is weird that I keep getting an error, that the m.movie_id does not exist, in spite of it existing there. Also, the t_movie table exists, so how does that work with it being automatically genrated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using different schemas. I found a solution to your problem:

`insert into public.movie(movie_id,movie_name) select t.movie_id, t.movie_name from test.movie as t;`

Comment: @ManasJani Check now for the new solution presented

Comment: that is the same solution that Gordon above suggested, but it keeps giving me the same error. I don't understand why!

Comment: Gordon's solution has a syntax error, I add `as` to name the query as **t** and the fields of that query are from table **t**. I tried it here and it worked perfectly this way

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem but I am not sure how to go about it. My select * from test.t_movies; works but when I want to do select movie_name from test.t_movies; it does not work. I tried doing the double quotes as well around the column name, but that does not work either.